# can't find module, tried appending sys path and checked perms

Tags: python

new to python and trying to use plotly and I somehow broke something...

did pip install plotly, that worked.
was able to do "import plotly" in CLI, ok all good

then wrote a script and named it plotly.py 
ran that and it can't find the module plotly

thinking the naming is causing a problem, I renamed my script to ptest.py, still can't find the module

read up here a bit... printing sys.path shows the directory plotly is in
checked the dir and made sure it is readable by all (it wasn't)

Still can't find the module

Added this to the script:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("path to module")
```

still can't find the module...

uninstall and reinstalled the module, no go.

Comment: Don't name your script `plotly.py`. Is the name of the module, this is likely creating a conflict and hiding the module.

Comment: I hope you have not set the path explicitly at OS level. Suggest you close that terminal or command window, open another one and try **import plotly** again and give a different name to your script.

Comment: I renamed the file, closed the terminal and opened a fresh one, same issue.. it looks like it's trying to find it in my home directory /Users/name/plotly.py...